# Regular Expression to Find Something Until String in Notepad++

Tags: regex, xml, notepad++

I'm trying to find a way to find and replace in Notepad++ and I can't figure out how to do the regex that would allow me to do so. I need to find all

```
<Element
          Attribute1="<!--Any one letter-->34_<!--Anything-->"
          <!--Multiple Attributes on multiple lines-->
          <!--Until-->
          AttributeToMatch="Value"
          <!--Multiple Attributes on multiple lines--> />
```

I want the following:

```
<Element
          Attribute1="<!--Any one letter-->34_<!--Anything-->"
          <!--Multiple Attributes on multiple lines-->
          <!--Until-->
          AttributeToMatch="NewValue"
          <!--Multiple Attributes on multiple lines--> />
```

I need to be able to replace only the "SpecificValue" with another Value for hundreds of elements so I wanted to find a way to do it more quickly and efficiently then doing it manually.

So far I came up with:

```
Attribute1="[A-Z]{1}34_.*(\r|\n)(\s)*.*(\r|\n)(\s)AttributeToMatch="SpecificValue"
```

Which doesn't work  (nothing is found) and I don't understand why.
Thanks

Comment: Okay, so the handiest way to do this is a big lookbehind and a lookahead, for example: (?<=\<Element.+Attribute1\=\".+34_.+\".?AttributeToMatch\=\")(?=\".?\/\>).

Give that a try. Edit: nah, sorry that lookbehind is probably invalid.

Comment: I know it's a pain but as you're working with XML anyway, why not put together a quick script to parse it, update it, then output it again as XML?

Comment: @struthersneil It is indeed invalid... In what language would you suggest doing the script?

Comment: I'd just use whatever you're comfortable with. python, ruby maybe. Anything with an easy-to-use XML library. But there probably *is* a regex solution. I'm going to tinker here for a minute.

Comment: Thank you for tinkering! I'll look into the python alternative, I haven't played with XML parsing yet, so I'll see what I can do!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I haven't tried this in Notepad++ specifically, but give it a go.

```
/\<Element[\S\s]*Attribute1\=\".*34_.*\"[\S\s]*AttributeToMatch\=\"([^\"]*)\"[\S\s]*\/\>[\S\s]*(?=\<Element)/igm
```

The `igm` is just notation that means it should be case insensitive, global, and multiline. Strip that off for Notepad++ probably.

You'll also need to be able to replace capture group $1 with your new value. Again, I'm not sure how that works in Notepad++.

The `[\S\s]*` groups match anything including newlines.

Finally, it avoids capturing more than one element at a time with a lookahead for `<Element`. It could also match the end of file if Notepad++ supports it, or add a fake

(My gut feeling remains that you'll have an easier time just parsing the XML and making the changes that way.)

Comment: Thanks again for this, but it doesn't work in Notepad++. In fact, it makes it crash! ^^'' I'm working on a Python script to parse the XML file and I'll use regex to filter out the elements with a matching Attribute1, than I'll just change the value of AttributeToMatch to what I want. I'll post how I did it when I'm done!